# Fetch a relation field's data in a single query

Tags: ios, parse-platform, relation

I encountered an old issue, here are discussions from 2 years ago:
https://www.parse.com/questions/help-with-a-simple-relational-query 
and 
https://www.parse.com/questions/how-to-get-multilevel-relationship-data

This is a key feature that seemed to be missing in the past, but I still encounter the same error while trying to use "includeKey" on a field of type "Relation" ("field  cannot be included because it is not a pointer to another object".

So I'm wondering, is there a way to do this nowadays?

Thank you very much.

Comment: AFAIK you still cannot have a field that is a Relation type as part of an includeKey on a query. The rationale seems to be that Relation types can support effectively an unlimited (or at least very large) number of related objects, and you could end up needing to transfer a very large amount of data to fulfil the request.

Comment: That makes some sense. But what if I wanted to have only the first 10 items of a relation, along with the main object, to avoid the second API call (at least until the user starts scrolling and then I'll get the next load of data)?

Comment: Then you're out of luck. You have to make 2 calls. Actually, you could do it via a cloud code function, but you still have 2 calls to the database (in cloud code) - you only avoid 1 from the mobile.

Comment: bummer... thanks anyway